# Find $f$ if $ f'(x) = \frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}} $

Tags: integration, derivatives

How can we find $f$ if its derivative is: 
$$
f'(x) = \frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}
$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? Have you tried anything on your own?  Do you know what "$u$-substitution" means, and have you tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make the substitution

$$u = \sqrt{1-4x^2}$$

so that

$$\text{d}u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}\cdot (-8x) = - \frac{4x}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}} \text{d}x$$

Thus you have a really easy integral because by operating that substitution you get:
$$\int -\frac{1}{2} \text{d}u = -\frac{1}{2}u$$

which is easy to backstep to $x$ variable, and gives you the result:

$$f(x) = -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-4x^2}$$

Comment: The result is correct, but $du = (-8x)/(\mathbf{2} \sqrt{1 - 4x^4})$, so the integral must be multiplied and divided by $-4$ and not $-2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. $$f^\prime(x)=\psi(x)\implies f(x)=\int\psi(x)\,\mathrm dx~~\text{(assuming that $f$ exists)}$$
2. Use an [u-substitution](https://brilliant.org/wiki/u-substitution/), particularly $1-4x^2=u^2$ with $u\,\mathrm du = -4x\,\mathrm dx$

Comment: The inconvenient of starting from a $u^2$ instead from a $u$ is when you solved the $u$ integral and get back to $x$: you have to make $u = \pm \sqrt{1 - 4x^2}$. Only the positive result shoud be considered, but why?

Comment: @BowPark, you're making the false assumption that $\sqrt{u^2}=u$ which is not true in general. It actually goes like this,
 
$$I=\int\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}\,\mathrm dx\overset{?}{=}-\frac 12\int\frac{u}{|u|}\,\mathrm du$$
 
When $u=\sqrt{1-4x^2}$, the integral reduces to,
 
$$I=-\frac 12\int\mathrm du=-\frac 12u+C=-\frac 12\sqrt{1-4x^2}+C$$
 
When $u=-\sqrt{1-4x^2}$, the integral reduces to,
 
$$I=-\frac 12\int -1\,\mathrm du=\frac 12u+C=-\frac 12\sqrt{1-4x^2}+C$$

Comment: I however do agree that starting with $u^2$ is just dumb, haha. We can always just take $u=\sqrt{1-4x^2}$ and then square it and go on our merry way as you suggest though, haha